# Container not starting

Tags: docker

I made a `docker` `container` of my web application.

At the end of the `docker` `build` command, I saw (which I suppose means that image was made)

```
Successfully tagged App:30may2020
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

When I run the `container`, I get error

`docker run  --publish 9000:9000 --detach --name App App:30may2020`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/App" is already in use by container "8a641431369c418e99ccb752161f5f2848d3c8f14bb903a18b6bd4aff2966af6". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Question 1 - Does `build` command also starts the container as I didn't start the container?
Question 2 - I did `docker container ls`  and `docker container ps` but I don't see my `container` running. Then why do I get the error?

Comment: You need to do `docker container ps -a`

Comment: Please add your `Dcokerfile` to the question that would help addressing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

*Question 1 - Does `build` command also starts the container as I didn't start the container?*

**Answer =>** No, but the command which you mentioned is a `run` command which will start the container.

```
docker run  --publish 9000:9000 --detach --name App App:30may2020
```

As you can see, `docker run` will start the container from the image `App:30may2020`.

*Question 2 - I did `docker container ls` and `docker container ps` but I don't see my container running. Then why do I get the error?*

**Answer2 =>** As the error says, `App` container name is already used by another container. There are below 2 ways to solve this

1. Run `docker rm App`, which will remove the container named `App` and if you want to see this container running run `docker ps -a`, and you would be able to see the container.

***Note***:- If you encounter an error while deleting the container, please stop the container first by running `docker stop App`.

2. The second way, don't give `--name` option while running the container and let docker choose the random name.

Answer (score 1):

If `docker ps` shows nothing, then you must already have a stopped container called `App`. When a container stops, it remains, so that it can be started again.

As commented above `docker ps -a` will show all containers both running and stopped.

To remove the stopped container, use `docker rm App`.

It's a good idea when manually running containers, especially whilst debugging (so you're going to stop and start many times) to use the `--rm` flag. This will ensure that the container is removed when it's stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Question1 answer: build doesn't starts a container

Question 2 answer: ps and ls display the container which are currently running but not those containers which are stopped. Do `docker ps -a` Incase if you want to view stopped containers. 
You are getting the error because you have already a container with the name '/App' try to run a container with a different name.
Or in case if you want to run container with same name but want to use from new build you should first stop and delete the container and you can run under a same name